# googleapis Unknown channel type nodeJs

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-workspace

I am trying to listen to events such as user is added to active directory in google workspace using googleapis , I have created adminSdk and its working fine with other functionalities but when I use user.watch with the parameters I provide it throws error.
code:

```
    this.adminSdk.users
      .watch({
        domain: this.domainName,
        event: 'ADD',
      })
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((err) => console.error('Error:::::>>>>>>>>>', err));
```

the error I get is

```
response code http
 {
      domain: 'push',
      reason: 'channelUnknown',
      message: 'Unknown channel type: '
    }
```

looked at documentation found nothing about channels